# Filter Issue with Isotope Filterable Grid Shortcode

Tags: javascript, wordpress, shortcode

Why is the filter functionality not working as expected in the "isotope_filterable_grid_shortcode" function?

```
function isotope_filterable_grid_shortcode($atts) {
    // Shortcode attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'category' => '',
    ), $atts);

    // Modify category order
    $category_order = array(
        'language',
        'play',
        'drawing',
    );

    // Query arguments
    $query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category_name' => $atts['category'],
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // Retrieve all posts
    );

    // Perform the query
    $posts_query = new WP_Query($query_args);

    // Start output buffer
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <style>
        .isotope-filterable-grid .isotope-grid {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .isotope-filterable-grid .grid-item {
            width: 30%;
            padding: 0.5rem;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 10px; /* Add margin-bottom to create a gap between columns */
            display: block; /* Set the grid items to be visible */
        }

        .isotope-filterable-grid .filter-buttons {
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .isotope-filterable-grid .filter-buttons button {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            background-color: #5c5858;          
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .isotope-filterable-grid .filter-buttons button.active {
            background-color: #14ae5c;
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="isotope-filterable-grid">
        <div class="filter-buttons">
            <button class="active" data-filter="*">All</button>
            <?php
            // Get all unique categories and reorder them
            $categories = get_categories();
            $categories_ordered = array();

            foreach ($category_order as $category_slug) {
                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    if ($category->slug === $category_slug) {
                        $categories_ordered[] = $category;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach ($categories_ordered as $category) {
                echo '<button data-filter=".' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name . '</button>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="isotope-grid">
            <?php if ($posts_query->have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while ($posts_query->have_posts()) : $posts_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="grid-item <?php echo implode(' ', get_post_class('', get_the_ID())); ?>">
                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                            <div class="featured-image">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <!-- Display your post content here -->
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p>No posts found.</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    // Reset post data
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Output the JavaScript code
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var $grid = $('.isotope-filterable-grid .isotope-grid');

            // Initialize Isotope
            $grid.imagesLoaded(function() {
                $grid.isotope({
                    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                });
            });

            // Filter items on button click
            $('.isotope-filterable-grid .filter-buttons button').on('click', function() {
                var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });

                // Update active button
                $('.isotope-filterable-grid .filter-buttons button').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
            
            // Show the grid items once Isotope has initialized
            $grid.find('.grid-item').css('opacity', 1);
            $grid.find('.grid-item').css('transform', 'scale(1)');
        });
    </script>

    <?php
    // Return buffered output
    return ob_get_clean();
}

// Register shortcode hook
add_shortcode('isotope_filterable_grid', 'isotope_filterable_grid_shortcode');
```

I have implemented a shortcode function called "isotope_filterable_grid_shortcode" that generates a filterable grid using Isotope.js. The grid displays posts based on their categories and allows users to filter the posts by category using buttons. However, the filter functionality is not working correctly.

I have defined the shortcode attributes and query arguments to retrieve the posts based on the provided category. I also included the necessary CSS styles for the grid layout and filter buttons. The grid is generated using the retrieved posts and the Isotope library is initialized to handle the filtering.

The issue arises when I click on the filter buttons. The grid items are not filtered accordingly, and the active button styling is not applied as expected. I suspect there might be an issue with the JavaScript code responsible for handling the filtering.

Could you please help me identify the problem and suggest a solution to fix the filter functionality in the "isotope_filterable_grid_shortcode" function?